# How to check if windows_path was being assigned in chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I have just started to use ChefSpec and am just investigating exactly what it allows

I have a chef recipe that installs Sublime and adds sublime to the path variable on windows:

```
chocolatey_package 'sublimetext3' do 
    action :upgrade 
end

windows_path node['sublime']['installation_path'] do 
    action :add 
    only_if { node['platform_family'] == 'windows' } 
end
```

Is it possible to test such a thing?

For example, something like:

```
it 'adds sublime to the machines path variable' do 
    expect(chef_run).to set_windows_path('pathtocheck')
end
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on this, or exactly what ChefSpec allows you to check for.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all resources follow the same pattern with matchers, `$action_$resourcetype('$resourcename')`. So in this case it would be:

```
expect(chef_run).to add_windows_path('pathtocheck')
```

Make sure that you set the `platform` and `version` options to ChefSpec so that you are using a Windows Fauxhai dump otherwise your `only_if` won't fire. (random protip you can use `platform_family?('windows')` in most contexts to save a bit of typing)